# php preg match between two strings

Tags: php, regex

How do I get the IpAddr values from this string below using preg match

```
{{Id=0|IpAddr=172.28.190.48|gateway=172.17.00.01|mask=255.255.255.240|pref=1}|{Id=0|IpAddr=172.30.228.64|gateway=172.17.01.02|mask=255.255.255.192|pref=1}|{Id=0|IpAddr=0.0.0.0|gateway=172.19.00.01|mask=0.0.0.0|pref=1}}
```

I tried below but it does not give results

```
preg_match_all("/.*IpAddr=(.*)\|/", $string, $result_array);
```

Comment: Just add the `U` modifier in existing your pattern and should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably matching to much and getting only 1 result, you would need lazy / ungreedy matching:

```
preg_match_all("/\bIpAddr=(.*?)\|/", $string, $result_array);
                             ^ Lazy / ungreedy match, take as few as possible
                 ^^ a word boundary before the IpAddr string
```

Comment: results in an array. Whats the pipe after the semi colon?

Comment: @SantoshPillai A typo... And you want an array I suppose as there are multiple matches.

Comment: I am writing only one occurrence and still its an array    preg_match_all("/\bIpAddr=(.*?)\|/",  $string, $result_array);
    $result = $result_array[1];  
    fwrite($file, '$result is ' . result . "\r\n");